# How to change dialog box message when cells in excel is readonly - with Apache POI XSSF

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I created an Excel with Apache POI XSSF. I needed to make certain columns readonly. so I set the sheet as protected and then set the cellstyle to unlocked for the editable columns.
When the user clicks on any of the non-editable columsn I get this message about the chart/sheet being protected and user needs a password to unprotect it. This is higly misleading since only certain columns are readonly.
How do I can change this alert message  ?

Comment: I am afraid you can't as this is a default Excel message. But the message exactly tells that the **cell** or chart **you're trying to change** is on a protected sheet. That's not misleading for me. If one tries changing not protected cells that message will not occur. Excel users should know this.